# Red5 Screensharing is not working in Ubuntu

Tags: java, jnlp, red5, screensharing

I have ubuntu environment. I want to have a screenshare option in my webapplication. I am using red5 for that. I can stream using red5, so thus no problem with installation.

I am using screenshare application from here.
https://code.google.com/p/red5-screenshare/downloads/list

I have followed everything mentioned here
http://devsteps.blogspot.in/2012/02/red5-screenshare.html

I runned it and started screen sharing. But the problem is, its not creating any screen_share.flv file in my streams folder. And, when I access screenviewer.html via

```
http://localhost:5080/screenshare/screenviewer.html
```

its giving only blank screen. 
What is the problem. Any suggestions?

**Edit :**

I don't know, whether its true or not. But red5-screenshare application is working with ubuntu-32 bit systems but not with 64-bit.
Now I installed 32-bit os. And, I say, partially this application is running.
But again getting few problems here.
I can able to see my screen but its giving output like this

[image]

Its may be because, I am viewing it in my computer (server and viewer is same) so, its coming like this (?).

And I have another problem also, Its not getting accessed in other systems. In other systems, I am only getting a blank screen. No console errors too. Unable to find a way to forward. Can anyone help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
First problem, as I guessed its because I am viewing my own screen so mirror views are generating.

Second problem, Its because of static url declaration. Here is the modification. In screenviewer.html

```
    var tot_url = document.URL; //url: http://192.x.x.x:5080/screenshare/screenviewer.html
    var http_removed_url = tot_url.split("//")[1]; //remove http:// from original url
    var ip_port = http_removed_url.split(":")[0];//filter only ip and port : 192.x.x.x:5080

    var stream = getPageParameter('stream', 'screen_share');
    var url = getPageParameter('url', 'rtmp://'+ip_port+'/oflaDemo');
```

And, it worked for me. A small bug is there, its not working in firefox. I think its different issue now.

Answer (score 1):

To have an flv file created in your streams directory the client application would need to be publishing in "record" mode, it is more than likely that it is publishing "live" instead. If you need it to record, you have to change the publish call in the client source or turn on recording for all streams via the servers red5.properties file.

```
broadcaststream.auto.record=true
```

Comment: No, I don't need to record it. I thought it might generate a flv file automatically. My problem is, I cant see anything in client side. Only a blank page.

Comment: It may be a bug in the application, I looked at their issue list and nothing obvious but I did see this https://code.google.com/p/red5-screenshare/issues/detail?id=9